# How to combine two array by underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am new for `underscorejs`,

First I have two arrays =>

```
var array1 = [1,2];

var array2 = [1,2];
```

How can I get like =>

```
[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

by using underscorejs?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Underscore is not required, nor it has such util function.

```
a.map(_a => b.map(_b => [_a, _b])).flat()
```

Or

```
a.flatMap(_a => b.map(_b => [_a, _b]));
```

```js
const a = [1, 2], b = [1, 2];
const out = a.map(_a => b.map(_b => [_a, _b])).flat();
console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```